# Getting no response after GET request call using Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, xcode, alamofire

Im writing a simple app to fetch data from a server and I have implemented the GET request using Alamofire using Swift3.
My Alamofire GET request call is as follows,

```
    func networkRequest(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request("https://api.waqi.info/feed/shanghai/?token=demo").responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        print(response.description)

        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let status = dict["status"] as? String {
                self._status = status
                print(self._status)
            }
       completed()
         }
       }
```

I have used a type alias as follows under the data model file,

```
    typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()
```

When I run this, I get no output in the console in Xcode 8, it remains blank. Im unable to figure out what is wrong in my code.

Comment: I've run the code and it is fine, there was correct output in the console. Try cleaning the project.

Comment: I did do that, yet in this particular case, it simply doesn't work. I even reinstalled the pods, I uninstalled the app on both simulator and on phone..installed again. The Xcode console simply remains blank. The UI label to which I have connected, remains blank too.

Comment: Are you doing this in a app or a command line script? If it's command line it may be that you need to call `dispatchMain()` to begin the libdispatch run loop. Otherwise your program will exit before the request has completed.

Comment: Yeah, it was a scoping issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was closing braces. Due to wrong scoping that, it wasnt getting called. Now its solved.